# R: Return the UTM zone that a WGS84 point belongs to

Tags: r, wgs84, utm

I'm looking for an R function that might work similarly to this website that will tell you what UTM zone your WGS84 point belongs to.

http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/converter.aspx

Comment: Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190198/how-to-get-appropriate-crs-for-a-position-specified-in-lat-lon-coordinates/190209#190209

Comment: @AndreJ this is even better than what I was asking for my particular problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each UTM zone is 6 degrees wide, so you can get the zone number by looking at the `longitude`:

```
floor((longitude + 180) / 6) + 1
```

This assumes that you have `longitude` within [-180.0, 180.0).