# How to convert from lat-lon to UTM with gdaltransform?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, utm, mgrs

I would like to transform the following coordinates

```
31.96212 -103.004715
```

to `UTM` with `gdaltransform`. I put coordinates into file `coordinates.txt` and ran

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:25832 < coordinates.txt
```

and got

```
ERROR 1: latitude or longitude exceeded limits 
transformation failed.
```

I also tried to reverse order to

```
-103.004715 31.96212
```

with the same result.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Valid area for EPSG:25832 is `Europe between 6°E and 12°E: Austria; Belgium; Denmark - onshore and offshore; Germany - onshore and offshore; Norway including - onshore and offshore; Spain - offshore.` Probably -103°E is too far from the valid area. The right coordinate order for GDAL is always longitude-latitude or easting-northing.

Comment: @user30184 so what to do? Can't I instruct GDAL to find area automatically?

Comment: GDAL does not have automatic UTM zone finder. The mathematics is not especially difficult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system and I suppose such tools exist.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224707/calculating-utm-zones-using-arcgis-pro, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209267/r-return-the-utm-zone-that-a-wgs84-point-belongs-to and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190198/how-to-get-appropriate-crs-for-a-position-specified-in-lat-lon-coordinates/190209#190209 for easy UTM zone calculation.