# Transform XY coordinates from within a custom flat geometry to latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, pyproj, xy, distance-matrix

I am looking for a Python based tool/API (PyProj?) that will help me transforming a set of XY points from within a custom flat map to latitude and longitude.

I have information about the latitude and longitude of (0, 0) point and also latitude and longitude of (Xmax, Ymax) point. The total area is not wider or longer than 400 meters.

It looks to me that PROJ/PyProj can do the job, however I am still lacking understanding how to initialize the thing.

Also, these XY points can be given as a matrix/table, so it would be nice if the tool can transform the whole data in vector implementation without the need to loop over all values.

Comment: If you are new to PyProj then you may find it useful to review our [self-assembling FAQ on PyProj](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyproj?tab=Frequent).

Comment: @PolyGeo, thank you very much. So I figured out (basing on this post [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190198/how-to-get-appropriate-crs-for-a-position-specified-in-lat-lon-coordinates] that I can create a custom CRS by using this command: `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=(latitude) +lon_0=(longitude) +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`. The transformation does transform the origin (0, 0) point correctly, but other points are not transformed correctly. Maybe because my north (in my custom CRS) does not point to actual north? What can I do to fix the transform?

Comment: I’m not a potential answerer of your question but it looks like you now have the knowledge to revise your question by using the [edit] button beneath it.  Once edited it should be in a better position to attract a potential answerer.